# calculate carriage from 0, 1 arrays

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to understand full-adder. I want to add two int arrays of 0, 1 with bit operation. But I can't understand how would I calculate the carriage from two arrays. According to wikipedia, C is a bit carried in from the next less significant stage. But how do I get it from two int arrays?

```
int c[sizeof(a)];
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++) {
    c[i] = (a[i] & b[i])
}
```

This is what I did but I am not sure if I am doing this right.

[Adding binary numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282825/adding-binary-numbers-in-c)

```
 for(i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
      sum[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ c); // c is carry
      c = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & c)) | (b[i] & c); 
 }
```

I understand the rest, but the answer does not show how to get c... Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

add

```
// sum = a xor b
// carriage_in = a and b

// carriage_out = a xor b xor carriage_in
// sum = a xor b xor carriage_out

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    int carriage = (a[i] & b[i]);
    sum[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ carriage);
    carriage = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & carriage)) | (b[i] & carriage);
}
```

Is this correct? I am so confused.

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [Add two numbers without using + and - operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279593/add-two-numbers-without-using-and-operators)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Full adder is 1 bit adder.

if You want to add single bits stored in two arrays.

For that you need to use `Bit wise OR` operation between two array elements.
and carry bit

if Any two of `carry,a[i] and b[i]` becomes 1.

`(carry==1 and a[i]==1) or (carry==1 and b[i]==1) or (a[i]==1 and b[i]==1)`.

Then there is a carry.set carry if above condition satisfies else reset it.

**EDIT**

Full adder code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[4]={1,1,0,1};
    int b[4]={1,0,0,1};
    int sum[5];
    int car=0;
    int i=0;

    for(i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum[i+1]=a[i]^ b[i] ^ car ;
        car=(a[i]&b[i])|(a[i]&car)|(b[i]& car);
        printf("%d=%d\n",sum[i+1],car);
    }
    sum[0]=car;


    printf("The result is: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d",sum[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand. Why do you set carriage as 1? And what do you mean by reset? set carriage as 0?

Comment: Yes.I did not set carriage as 1 , just checking against 1. and if that condition satisfies you need to make carriage value 1 for next iteration check. if there is only one 1 out of three this wont produce carry .so you need to make carriage zero that is reset.

Comment: I added my implementation which does resetting with loop. Is it correct?

Comment: added full adder implementation. That works for you. try to understand each step and read about full adder.

Comment: `sum[i+1]=a[i]^ b[i] ^ car`, sorry misguided here. This should not be `|` and should be `^`.

Comment: It should be `sum[i] = a[i] ^ b[i] ^ car;`. Also `sum[4] = car;`

Comment: may i know why it should be sum[i] not sum[i+1].

Comment: sorry you miss understood my implementation. if you see for loop then you might change your opinion

Comment: OK - I see - you have reversed the order of the bits. Normally the bit whose index is 0 is considered to be the least significant bit. The way you have written it the indices for the inputs and the sum are off by one. See my answer with a fixed version of the OP's code for a more comventional implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The last code example you provide is almost correct, and it actually has fewer problems than the accepted answer from @Gangadhar. You just need a couple of changes to get the initial state of the carry flag correct:

```
int carriage = 0;                     // init carry in
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    sum[i] = a[i] ^ b[i] ^ carriage;  // half add - you got this part right !
    carriage = (a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & carriage) | (b[i] & carriage);
                                      // generate new carry - you got this
}                                     // part right also !
```